# Download pdf file after submitting the Hubspot form in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I want to create a functionality where on each page there will be an option to download a PDF file which is page specific, and when user clicks on the button to download a popup will be created which will first ask the user to fill a form(Its a Hubspot form) and on clicking submit it will download the PDF file in user's local machine.

Can any one help me with this!! I am new to Wordpress and PHP

Comment: simply used jquery and hubspot form submit button on click and then download the pdf, you also give the unique class for hubspot from your hubspot account by default is "hs-button".

Answer (score -1):

You can use this plugin for uploading the pdf file from admin side in the pages you want. Here is the link - https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/. You can follow the steps mentioned in the plugin page for the installation an deployment.
Also you can use jQuery for displaying the hubspot page and submitting for pdf to download.